# Зачем нужен 4 конструктор std::bitset, когда есть 3?

Tags: c++, c++11

Класс [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) имеет несколько конструкторов. Один из них (3) имеет вид:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc >
explicit bitset( const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& str,
             typename std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::size_type pos = 0,
             typename std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::size_type n =
                 std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>::npos,
             CharT zero = CharT('0'),
             CharT one = CharT('1'));
```

Другой (4):

```
template< class CharT >
explicit bitset( const CharT* str,
             typename std::basic_string<CharT>::size_type n =
                 std::basic_string<CharT>::npos,
             CharT zero = CharT('0'),
             CharT one = CharT('1'));
```

Зачем нужен конструктор (4), когда есть (3)?

И в частности, зачем использовать `CharT*` вместо `std::basic_string`?

Comment: а там не написано? `Similar to (3), but uses a CharT* instead of a std::basic_string`

Comment: @pavel "зачем" != "чем отличается"

Comment: вот тут можно почитать, для чего нужны специализации `const char*` http://gcc.1065356.n8.nabble.com/Add-const-char-constructors-for-exception-classes-in-lt-stdexcept-gt-td996792.html

Comment: Так в чем суть вопроса-то? Автор подразумевает, что при необходимости функциональность варианта 4 будет покрыта функциональностью варианта 3 засчет (явного или неявного) преобразования С-строки к типу `std::string`? Или суть вопроса в чем-то другом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, что это связано с включенной новой возможностью в стандарт C++ в качестве аргумента использовать список инициализации в фигурных скобках.

Дело в том, что все конструкторы класса объявлены со спецификатором функции `explicit`, чтобы предотвратить неявное преобразование объектов других типов в объекты класса.

В этом случае если вы вызовите конструктор класса с аргументом в фигурных скобках с одним типом, то не будет преобразования объектов списка инициализации в другой тип.

Сравните эти две демонстрационные программы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A
{
    explicit A( const std::string & ) {}
};


int main() 
{
    A a( "HEllo" );

    return 0;
}
```

Данная программа будет успешно компилироваться. Аргумент конструктора из типа литерала преобразуется в тип объекта класса `std::string`.

Теперь заключите аргумент вызова конструктора в фигурные скобки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A
{
    explicit A( const std::string & ) {}
};


int main() 
{
    A a( { "HEllo" } );

    return 0;
}
```

Данная программа уже не будет компилироваться.

Поэтому если вы включите еще один конструктор со спецификатором `explicit`, то программа уже будет компилироваться

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A
{
    explicit A( const std::string & ) {}
    explicit A( const char * ) {}
};


int main() 
{
    A a( { "HEllo" } );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а почему преобразование становится возможным? у нас же explicit стоит... или можно неявно преобразовывать {T} к T?

Comment: @poop Здесь имеет место прямая инициализация параметра конструктора аргументом. Если бы вы написали, например, A a = "Hello";, то уже быдо бы сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: можете дать ссылку, где об этой инициализации почитать?

Comment: @poop Это вам надо смотреть раздел стандарта 8.5 Initializers . Ищите в интернете желательно последний рабочий проект стандарта C++

Comment: спасибо буду смотреть

Comment: Вы в курсе, что код, который по Вашим словам должен не собираться, собирается clang и vc++?

Comment: @alexolut Надо юудет внимательно просмотреть стандарт. Я займусь этим. По крайней мере компилятор MS VC++ е внушает доверия.

Comment: Удалось посмотреть Стандарт? Я, кажется, знаю ответ на вопрос ТС. Если поспособствуете открытию вопроса - напишу.

Comment: @alexolut  Я проголосовал переоткрыть вопрос.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ответ готов.

Answer (score 3):

Суть наличия конструктора (4), а также замены `std::basic_string` на `const charT*` кроется в механизме перегрузке функций. А конструктор, как известно, тоже выбирается на основании переданных в него аргументов.

Для понимания сути можно заменить конструкторы на обычные функции, убрать лишние параметры и упростить типы. В таком случае мы можем получить пару функций вида:

```
void b(const std::string& str, int pos = 0, int n = 100500); // 1 
void b(const char* str, int n = 100500); // 2
```

Можно заметить, что функции имеют параметры по умолчанию, т.е. функцию (1) можно вызвать использую 1-3 параметра, а функцию (2), используя 1-2 параметра.

Известно, что значения по умолчанию можно давать только последним параметрам функции. Т.е. если нам важно задать только `pos` и оставить `n` по умолчанию - мы используем версию (1), а если задать только `n`, но оставить `pos` - версию (2).

И вот тут важно, чтобы первый (обязательный) параметр имел в разных перегрузках разных тип, т.к. если бы версия (2) вместо `const char*` имела бы `const std::string&` возникла бы [неоднозначность выбора](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PJE0QnrwMKWFcuyN) перегрузки например для вызова вида:

```
b("str", 10);
```

Но так как типы разные - [вызывается именно версия](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rquUGdqcw0ZtyCj3) (2).

Comment: Хорошее объяснение.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow надо ещё компиляторы вывести на чистую воду в Вашем варианте.

Comment: Да, желательно.